# Как сделать "отскакивание" в RecycleView вначале и в конце

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать "отскакивание" в RecycleView вначале и в конце. Пример эффекта в GIF на первом фото. Т.е. когда нет следующего элемента, как сдвигать текущий элемент и чтобы он возвращался обратно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Фича называется *overscroll* или *bouncy*.

На гитхабе с десяток реализаций отскакивания, например:

- [OverScrollBouncy](https://github.com/chthai64/overscroll-bouncy-android)
- [overscroll-decor](https://github.com/EverythingMe/overscroll-decor)

Ну и т.д.